# where does sublime store unsaved files?

Tags: windows, sublimetext2

where does sublime store unsaved files?

I like how when there is a crash the unsaved files are still there.

Where does sublime store them - what directory?

Comment: Probably a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415999/where-does-sublime-text-2-store-editing-information

Comment: i'd note, while the question says "I like how when there is a crash the unsaved files are still there." ..  I had an issue a yaer or two after posting this, where all the files blanked out and I lost stuff from it.. some files were being read off the network.  I don't think many use sublime anymore.  I still use notepad.  Many use Atom.

Comment: Probably a better question for SuperUser, see https://superuser.com/questions/894021/where-does-sublime-text-store-its-un-saved-windows for more answers

Comment: @JamesMcMahon debatable.. If SO accepts it (and it clearly does or did), then there'd always be a better response on SO 'cos SO has a much larger userbase and lots of expert programmers who use whichever platform for their programming  as a barebones IDE, and know the ins and outs of it).  I notice it just picked up a close vote now, i don't know if that's from you. But clearly it was acceptable for 9+years and there is even a tag for Sublime. If you think Sublime isn't relevant here then maybe question why there is a tag for Sublime(used as a barebones programming IDE!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For windows, the default is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local`.

For iOS, `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/`.

For linux, `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/`.

The unsaved sessions can be found at "Auto Save Session.sublime_session".

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text version 4 (Windows):

```
<Your_Installation_folder>\Data\Local\Session.sublime_session
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For `Sublime Text 2` I found session file `Session.sublime_session` in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/`.